# Backup installed packages in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in a VM using VirtualBox. I planned to learn android development and downloaded some sources to the VM. I downloaded it in my brother's net,which is really fast. Now, I came back to my area. The net is very very slow. (15kbps max dl).

I would like to backup the downloaded packages and restore them to a new different VM (Ubuntu 13.04).

I have read that the solution: Save a list of the installed packages.
But, it is not possible for me to re-download everything... Please help me...

Comment: Keep in mind that even if you save the packages, there is no guarantee that they will work on a different OS version. You probably need to re-download them.

Answer (score 0):

apt (Ubuntu's default package manager) caches the packages it downloads in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. They're most likely still there, so you can copy them from there and install them via the Software Center (by double-clicking on them in the file manager).

Comment: I'm aware that you can use `dpkg -i some-package.deb`, but using the Software Center seems more beginner-friendly to me.